# mongoDB how to query array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

is it posibale to query something like this:

```
db.translations.find({'key'["select_trip_type_title","select_trip_type_title"]}})
```

my translations collection looks like that

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8e6a53134bdd79eadb081e"),
    "status" : "active",
    "key" : "select_trip_type_title",
    "default_value" : "Select Trip Tyoe ",
    "value" : "Select Trip Tyoe ",
    "operator" : ObjectId("5c8e6a52134bdd79eadb0812"),
    "language" : ObjectId("5c8e6a52134bdd79eadb0814"),
    "version" : 0.1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-17T15:40:03.536Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-03-17T15:40:03.536Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8e6a53134bdd79eadb081e"),
    "status" : "active",
    "key" : "select_trip_type_title",
    "default_value" : "Select Trip Tyoe ",
    "value" : "Select Trip Tyoe ",
    "operator" : ObjectId("5c8e6a52134bdd79eadb0812"),
    "language" : ObjectId("5c8e6a52134bdd79eadb0814"),
    "version" : 0.1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-17T15:40:03.536Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-03-17T15:40:03.536Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8e6a53134bdd79eadb0823"),
    "status" : "active",
    "key" : "set_location_on_map_action_positioning",
    "default_value" : "positioning...",
    "value" : "positioning...",
    "operator" : ObjectId("5c8e6a52134bdd79eadb0812"),
    "language" : ObjectId("5c8e6a52134bdd79eadb0814"),
    "version" : 0.1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-17T15:40:03.536Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-03-17T15:40:03.536Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

and if I have those keys than get them.

my main missions are to get a diff between the keys in the query array and those in the collection

Comment: What is your `translations` collection looks like and what actually do you want to find?

Comment: something like that
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8e6a53134bdd79eadb081b"),
    "status" : "active",
    "key" : "select_trip_type_short_trip",
    "value" : "Short Trip"
}


I need to query through all collection and find which one not there.

get something like a diff?

Comment: Now your question is unclear, as there is nothing like 1,2,2 or 1,2,3 in the `key` field. Please update your post with details.

Comment: Is your question actually is to find all the documents where is key either like "select_trip_type_title" or "select_trip_type_short_trip", etc? Meaning anything inside the array `["select_trip_type_title", "select_trip_type_short_trip"]`

Comment: yes, I need to find anything that inside in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator like:

```
db.translations.find({
  "key": {
    $in: ["select_trip_type_title", "select_trip_type_short_trip"]
  }
})
```